# Windows Phone - Passing Data With OnNavigatedFrom's NavigationEventArgs. Can there be memory leak?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

So my scenario is that a page1.xaml has a list of items that are clickable. Say, item#1, #2, #3. Upon clicking any of them, a user is presented with page2.xaml (for example, a user needs to log in before seeing the content of item#1, #2, or #3).

So, the page2.xaml has a "login" button. Clicking which the app should log the user in, and display a "next page". The "next page" can be the content of item#1, #2, or #3.

I do not want to store the next page as a string of a relative url, for example, because the "next page" may need parameters. For example, to display item#2, I need to pass the item id and a bunch of other parameters.

So, I need to set page2.xaml in a way that it knows the "next page" and the parameters to pass when navigating to that next page.

Here is the code I came up...
We have page#1.

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
private object[] parametersForNextPage;
protected override OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Content is Page2 )
        {
            if (parametersForNextAction != null)
            {
                var mm = (Page2)e.Content;
    // The reason why I need to set mm.NextPage and mm.parameters is because the NextPage could be any page
                mm.NextPage = HandleActionFunc; // This is some another function that will be called after Page2        
                mm.parameters = parametersForNextPage; // HandleActionFunc needs parameters
            }
        }
}
    private void Item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (SomeRandomUserControlDefinedByMe)sender;
            parametersForNextPage = control.parameters;
    PageNavController.NavigateToPage2();
}
}
```

Then, we have page#2:

```
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
public object[] parameters;
public Action<object[]> goToNextPage;
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //...//
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GoToNextPage(parameters);
}
}
```

Now, the question I have is... can this lead to memory leak?

I'm not quite sure about this one...

Page2 will have a parameters field which is a reference to Page1's 
parametersForNextPage.

Does that mean that when Page1 goes to Page2, Page2 will keep the Page1 from being Garbage collected because it holds a reference to a Page1's field?

But even if this is the case, when navigating from Page2 to a "next page"... will garbage collector now erase Page1 AND Page2?

I may have been unclear as I'm not used to posting coding questions online, but hopefully, someone can help me clear the doubts about how Garbage collection in this case works.

This may not be the best way to pass data, btw, and if this is the case, feel free to suggest me another way to do this logic.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

With `parametersForNextPage`, you don't keep a reference to Page1, you keep a reference to an object referenced by Page1. There is therefore no problem with the garbage collector.

I'd be more worried about `HandleActionFunc`. You don't show it, but if it's an instance method declared on Page1, then it **will** prevent the garbage collector from cleaning Page1.

That said, you must keep in mind that Page1 will be kept in memory for as long as it's present in the back-stack. So if you don't intend to clear the back-stack when you navigate on Page2, you have nothing to worry about because Page1 will be kept alive either way.